Can I force a specific app to always show scroll bars?
I'd like my text editor, Nova, to always show scroll bars.
I know you can make them always show globally through System Settings > Appearance > Show scroll bars > Always
But is there a way, perhaps using defaults, of forcing this setting per-app?

That may be possible. Since you're asking the question, I assume there is no setting in the UI such as "Always show scroll bar." You first have to find out the preference domain for the app. Probably this will do it:
defaults domains | tr , $'\n' | grep -i nova

Let's say the domain is 'com.foo.nova'. Quit the app if it's running, then:
defaults write com.foo.nova AppleShowScrollBars Always

To revert to the global setting:
defaults delete com.foo.nova AppleShowScrollBars


Perfect! Thank you. FWIW the domain was com.panic.Nova. And no there is no app setting to do this.

I turned this into an Nova Extension https://extensions.panic.com/extensions/com.gingerbeardman/com.gingerbeardman.scrollbars/
